# Why does git log return unexpected results when executed inside a JavaScript GitHub Action?

Tags: javascript, git, yaml, github-actions

From my command line, if I execute the following two `git log` commands (to print the filenames in a commit), they return the expected output:

```
$ git log -1 --name-only --pretty=format: c0ddab
lib/ow/css.js

$ git log -1 --name-only --pretty=format: fc3039
.github/workflows/github-actions-demo.yml
```

But if the same two commands are executed from inside a JavaScript GitHub Action, they do not return the same--they return:

```
/usr/bin/git log -1 --name-only --pretty=format: c0ddab
 c0ddab
.github/workflows/github-actions-demo.yml// This is not the file that was modified in this commit.

/usr/bin/git log -1 --name-only --pretty=format: fc3039
 fc3039
.github/workflows/github-actions-demo.yml
```

Anyone know why that's happening or how I can troubleshoot?  See below for the full code from my JavaScript Action

---

**My Code**

*My YML File*

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
on: [push]
jobs:
  Job-1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Test JS action
        id: hello
        uses: myUsername/myRepo@master
```

*My JavaScript Action (index.js; in myUsername/myRepo@master)*

```
const exec = require("@actions/exec");

async function myAAFunc() {
  let commitSha;
  const options = {};

  commitSha = "c0ddab";
  await exec.exec(
    "git",
    ["log", "-1", "--name-only", `--pretty=format: ${commitSha}`],
    options
  );

  commitSha = "fc3039";
  await exec.exec(
    "git",
    ["log", "-1", "--name-only", `--pretty=format: ${commitSha}`],
    options
  );
}

myAAFunc();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript code executes the equivalent of :

```sh
git log -1 --name-only "--pretty=format: fc3039"
```

When you pass an array of strings to `exec.exec()`, it doesn't parse the strings to try to split arguments, it just passes each string unmodified as an individual argument to your command.

---

The fix is easy : split `"--pretty=format:"` and `commitSha` as two distinct arguments :

```js
await exec.exec(
    "git",
    ["log", "-1", "--name-only", "--pretty=format:", commitSha],
    options
);
```

Comment: OK brilliant--thanks so much for that, it worked. I remember at the time I wrote that code I thought to myself, "You're trying to take a shortcut here--let's see if it works."  And it did indeed work as expected, for that particular use case.  I forgot to go back and fix it, and here I am.  Thanks again!